# How to use pdfcrop on Overleaf or TeXworks?

Tags: pdfcrop

I only use Overleaf and I need to use pdfcrop package, but I have no idea how it is supposed to be used. I have downloaded the package from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop), and I tried uploading its files to an Overleaf project and try to write:

\usepackage{pdfcrop}
\pdfcrop{name.pdf}

where the file I want to crop is called 'name.pdf'. This didn't work, as the package and command was not recognised.

I could try using TeXworks, by adding the command line 'pdfcrop in.pdf out.pdf', but I'm not sure what else is needed. Can anyone please help?

Comment: there is not (as far as I know) a latex package called `pdfcrop`, what exactly do you need to do, you can crop a pdf file while including it into latex by using teh viewport or trim options to `\includegraphics`

Comment: I am asked to use pdfcrop to crop figures. It is this package: https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop . Is it supposed to be used somewhere else on your computer if not via LaTeX? Thanks

Comment: it is a commandline script (using pdflatex internally) that crops a pdf but if you use it at all you just do it once to modify your pdf _before_ you upload to overleaf there is no matching latex `\usepackage` and you do not want to dothis every time you run latex it is a one-off edit to your images. But were you really asked to changethe included pdf or simply remove white space from the resulting document by cropping the inclusion which you can do via `\includegraphiics[clip,trim=1in 1in 1in 1in]{yourfile.pdf}` adjusting the lengths for whatever you need.